# Ruby on Rails - How to Use HTML Coordinates in a Rails Method?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, geolocation, coordinates

Thanks to whoever will answer me.

I have a method that currently works like this `post.distance_to([current_user.latitude, current_user.longitude])`. It returns the distance between a post (with an address) and the current_user.

I created the attributes latitude and longitude in the user model because I don't know how to use directly these coordinates that I retrieve with the following script:

```
<p id="geoloc"></p>
<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("geoloc");

  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCoordinates);
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
  }

  function getCoordinates(position) {
    var new_latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var new_longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#latitude_field").val(new_latitude);
      $("#longitude_field").val(new_longitude);
    }
  }

  getLocation()
</script>
```

Currently I'm updating the user model with the new coordinates by pressing a button using this form:

```
<%= form_for(current_user) do |f|  %>
  <%=f.hidden_field :latitude ,:id=> "latitude_field" %>
  <%=f.hidden_field :longitude ,:id=> "longitude_field" %>
  <%=f.submit "I'm here", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary jsbuttons"%>
<%end%>
```

What I would like to do is calling the method directly like this `post.distance_to(["latitude obtained with the script", "longitude obtained with the script"])`. How can I make rails know what those coordinates are? Can I use those javascript id I use in the form to just get the values and place them in the method somehow?
Thanks!

If that's too complicated can I update the user model with the new coordinates every time I refresh the page without having to press a button? (I tried to make an id for the form and place a submit in the `$(document).ready(function)` for that id but it didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for your form:

```
<%= form_tag '/your_url' do |f|  %>
  <%=f.text_field_tag :latitude, params[:latitude], :id=> "latitude_field" %>
  <%=f.text_field :longitude, params[:longitude], :id=> "longitude_field" %>
  <%=f.submit "I'm here", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary jsbuttons"%>
<% end %>
```

Now in your controller action you access lat/long using:

```
lat = params[:latitude]
lng = params[:longitude]
distance = post.distance_to([lat,lng])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, is this a way to update a model every time I refresh a page? with "/your_url" you mean the url of the page right? but in that form tag how can the form know he has to change the latitude and longitude attributes of the current_user?
Also I guess I should update the syntax (changing from form_form to form_tag) with submit_tag and no "f"? Thanks!

in the second part do you mean I have to set in the update action of the user controller
@user.latitude= params[:latitude] and same for longitude?

Comment: @orim as I understood you wanted to decouple coordinates from user, right? But now it looks like you mean something different. Can you please first shortly define what are you doing. Then I can respond more precisely.

Comment: I have a page in which an user can see the posts that have an address close to him.
I have an if that says that 'if post.distance_to(current.user.latitude, current_user.longitude)' is less than 15 miles, the user can see the post.
What I want is to take these latitude and longitude from the script (the position.coords.latitude and longitude), and either call the method directly on them 'post.distance_to(latitude from the script, longitude from the script)' (in this case I wouldn't need the lat and long attributes in the user) or update the user model in a hidden way with the new coordinates

Comment: *update the user model with the new coordinates every time I refresh the page (the Neighborhood Home Page).
I know they are different approaches to the problem, but for my purpose whichever is the simpler is fine

Comment: So you first display page with form, user clicks "I'm here" and then he's redirected to posts page (which are close to him). Is it right?

Comment: currently the button (and the form) is in the same page of the posts close to him

Comment: the form is actually hidden (except for the submit button)